# blog posts sorting doesnt work while using get_query_var

Tags: posts, sort

I'm trying to show the latest posts using the `get_query_var` function. The function filters the posts according to their category.
When I'm displaying the posts on the page they appear unsorted although I've added the

`$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;`
 `$args=array(`
   `'category__in'=>array( $cat),`
   `'order' => ASC,`
   `'caller_get_posts' => 1,`
   `'paged'=>$paged,`
   `'orderby' => date,`
   `);`
   `query_posts($args);`

How can I sort properly?

Comment: im using wordpress with buddypress

Comment: Hi Jan, i fixed the orderby but it still doesnt work. here is the code. paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args=array(
   'category__in'=>array( $cat),
   'order' => ASC,
   'caller_get_posts' => 1,
   'paged'=>$paged,
   'orderby' => date,
   );
query_posts($args);

Comment: @peroxide: I've added your update to the question, but you can do this yourself too. You use the `paged` parameter to control paging, but that should have no effect on sorting. This should be done by the `order` and `orderby` parameters (and even if you leave it out, ordering by date is the default). Are you sure no other query is running before you display the posts? Can you give the code up and including the `have_posts()` and related lines? In what file did you place this code?

Comment: Hi @Jan, i've updated my post and entered the complete code. it's located inside the archive.php file

Comment: @peroxide: What is the reason you execute `query_posts()` again? Doesn't the default category archive query do what you want? Anyway, I would also put `ASC` and `date` in quotes, to make sure they are interpreted as strings.

Comment: Hi @Jan, the query_posts() was removed, i've also added the ASC and date in quotes as you mentioned before but it still doesnt work. it shows the posts unsorted. maybe something else is bothering the function from running?

Comment: @peroxide: I have tried your code on my local installation, as the `archive.php` page, and it shows the posts. They are ordered, on date, ascending, so the oldest post is first (which is the opposite of the normal order, but you use `ASC` in your example). If I completely remove the call to `query_posts()`, I still see the posts, with the normal order, so newest on top. Paging works too. Or do you mean you get the oldest-to-newest but meant newest-to-oldest? In that case it's the `ASC` that should be `DESC`, and that we both missed.

Comment: Hi @Jan: i've also removed the query_posts() and still the results are not sorted. have you tried it with buddypress. do you need that i will publish a different file? maybe the problem is with something else with the installation?

Comment: @peroxide: No, I have tried it with the regular WordPress, not BuddyPress. I have never used BuddyPress, but I can't imagine it would do something with the sorting of `query_posts()`. Maybe another plugin? Have you tried disabling all plugins, to see whether one of them hooks into the query and changes settings? Is the order always different (random)? Or is it by ID, by title, ...? Is this an on-line example that we can access?

Comment: Hi @Jan, i think you have found the problem. i've noticed that the paging is controlled by a plugin called wp-pagenavi. when i disable it there is no paging at all. i will check its compatibility with buddypress and tell you if thats the problem we were trying to fix. thanks

Comment: @peroxide: In that case I'll post my last comment as an answer so that you can accept it, and we know this question is solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If something unexpected happens between `query_posts()` and `get_post()`, it is probably a plugin that hooks into the query and modifies it. Try disabling all plugins to see whether the problem disappears. Re-enable them one by one until you see the problem, that is the plugin that causes it.